# veins_hetvnet project path and variable error

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulte

I imported [this recommended project](https://github.com/veins/veins_hetvnet) into `OMNeT++` to find out how to combine `80211p` and `LTE` communication in my simulation.

It's recommended to use `Veins 5.0-alpha2`, `OMNeT++ 5.5.1`, `INET 3.6.5`, `SimuLTE 1.0.1` for this project.

But I'm using `Veins 5.0`, `OMNeT++ 5.6.2`, `INET 3.6.6`, `SimuLTE 1.1.0`.

When I import that project into the environment I have configured, the path problem occurs as shown in the following image.

[image: Situation]

I changed the `Car.ned` code of `veins_hetvnet` as follows.

```
// Original
import lte.stack.phy.ILteNic;
// Modify
import lte.stack.ILteNic;
```

After making this change, the import error is resolved, but the `lteNic` submodule `d2dCapable` variable error occurs.

Do I have to configure the same environment to run this project?

Unfortunately I don't understand how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above my problem is resolved. Using `SimuLTE 1.1.0`, I was unable to fix the error by modifying the code. Therefore, I used `git reset` command.

First, cloning repository to your machine.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/inet-framework/simulte.git
```

Second, reset commit from cloned repository.

```
$ git reset --hard fa994699
```

That's it!

You can now use `SimuLTE 1.0.1` and you can use the `veins_hetvnet` project normally.